# FastAPI: "There was an error parsing the body" when the body contains Chinese

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

Here is a demo from fastapi document

```py
from typing import Union

from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
import uvicorn


class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    description: Union[str, None] = None


app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/items")
async def create_item(item: Item):
    return item


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, port=8000)
```

We use curl to post data to this api

```bash
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/items'  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  -d '{"name":"my_project5","description":"hahaha" }'    # good

curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/items'  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  -d '{"name":"my_project5","description":"哈哈哈" }'    # error
```

Is there any way to fix this problem? Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: I ran your example, and for me, it works

Comment: You might have an issue with the encoding in your terminal not handling the Chinese characters as UTF-8.

Comment: When I changed the terminal to the postman, it works!  Thanks a lot